# How do I remove certain elements from an array in Java?

Tags: java

If I have an array of numbers, say 5, 6, 8, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, so the length of my array is 9, and I want to shorten the array so that all the elements equal to 0 are removed from the end until the first non-zero element is reached, how do I do that?  In short, I want my new array to be 5, 6, 8, 1, 0, 5.

Comment: Do you understand how to use a for loop?

Comment: What *have* you tried? Right now, it looks like you want the community to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is

- get the start index with a linear search from the end
- allocate a new `dest` array with the correct length
- Use [`System.arraycopy( src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length );`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) with `srcPos` and `destPos` set to zero

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the index of last non-zero element by looping from reverse.

```
int i=arr.length-1;
for(;i>=0;i--)
   if(arr[i]!=0)break;
```

Now, once you have index, either you can start loop from the `index=0` till last non-zero element index and add it to ArrayList.

or

as suggested by @Aubin use `arraycopy`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :) :

```
 int[] array = new int[] {5,2,1,2,0,5,0,5,7,0,8,0,0};
//find fisrt not null from end
   int index=findFirstNotNull(array);
   int[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(array, index+1);

 public  int findFirstNotNull(int[] arr){
  int index=0; 
  for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if(arr[i]!=0){
      index= i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```